# 1 user session java app and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface, authentication

Well I'm learning mysql and java, and I'm trying to do a Login app, Server - client MySQL.

The problem is that the same user can login in more than 1 pc at time. I want just to let the user be logged in 1 pc at time, if he logs out he can get logged in other pc.

I thought to put an status column inside a table in the DB, but if the connection to the server is lost there's no way to change the status of the user.

So what could be a good way to solve it. I hope I explained clearly.

Comment: The connection from where is lost to what server? The client browser loses the connection to the application server?

Comment: From the mysql server, not the java app

Comment: Save a status and timestamp for the last successful login might work as answered by shahart. About the application lost connection to the database, you can use a distributed storage like, memcache, redis, Cassandra and go on to save the login session

Answer (score 0):

Add a timestamp on this status, update it on every user's action. If there's time out (simulates connection loss) or session logout, then update the status to 'not logged in'

Comment: Thanks for answering, maybe that solves both. so your solution is adding a time counter if I get it.